# Add and fill missing columns with values of 0s in pandas matrix [python]

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, indexing

I have a matrix of the form :

```
movie_id   1     2     3     ...   1494    1497   1500
user_id                                                               
1600       1.0   0.0   1.0   ...   0.0     0.0    1.0
1601       1.0   0.0   0.0   ...   1.0     0.0    0.0
1602       0.0   0.0   0.0   ...   0.0     1.0    1.0
1603       0.0   0.0   1.0   ...   0.0     0.0    0.0
1604       1.0   0.0   0.0   ...   1.0     0.0    0.0
.          ...
.
.
```

As you can see even though the movies in my dataset are 1500, some movies haven't been recorded cause of the preprocess that my data has gone through.

What i want is to add and fill all the columns (movie_ids) that haven't been recorded with values of 0 (I don't know which movie_ids haven't been recorded exactly). So for example i want a new matrix of the form:

```
movie_id   1     2     3     ...   1494    1495   1496 1497 1498 1499 1500
user_id                                                               
1600       1.0   0.0   1.0   ...   0.0     0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
1601       1.0   0.0   0.0   ...   1.0     0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 
1602       0.0   0.0   0.0   ...   0.0     0.0    0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
1603       0.0   0.0   1.0   ...   0.0     0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1604       1.0   0.0   0.0   ...   1.0     0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
.          ...
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) along `axis=1` with `fill_value=0` to conform the dataframe columns to a new index range:

```
df = df.reindex(range(df.columns.min(), df.columns.max() + 1), axis=1, fill_value=0)
```

Result:

```
movie_id     1     2     3      1498  1499  1500
user_id                                     
1600       1.0   0.0   1.0         0     0   1.0
1601       1.0   0.0   0.0         0     0   0.0
1602       0.0   0.0   0.0 ...     0     0   1.0
1603       0.0   0.0   1.0 ...     0     0   0.0
1604       1.0   0.0   0.0         0     0   0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume variable name of the matrix is `matrix`

```py
n_moovies = 1500
moove_ids = matrix.columns

for moovie_id in range(1, n_moovies + 1):
    # iterate over id-s
    if moovie_id not in moove_ids:
        # if there's no such moovie create a column filled with zeros
        matrix[moovie_id] = 0
```